# Left outer join shows incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a simple left outer join.

The inner queries work fine. But as soon as I do a left outer join, I get an error saying 'Incorrect syntax near T1' and 'Incorrect syntax near T2'.

I don't know where am I wrong. Am I including a where condition which I should not in the inner queries ??

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM Table1 
 WHERE MMID IN 
       (SELECT MAX(MMID) 
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE (DateEntered) >= '2015-04-15 15:17:03.693'
        GROUP BY GID, MID)
) T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE (DateEntered) < '2015-04-15 15:17:03.693') T2 ON T1.GID = T2.GID AND T1.MID = T2.MID 
WHERE
    T1.Value <> T2.Value
```

Comment: What's your SQLServer release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this your actual query there's the outer SELECT missing:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE MMID IN (
            SELECT MAX(MMID)
            FROM Table1
            WHERE (DateEntered) >= '2015-04-15 15:17:03.693'
            GROUP BY GID
                ,MID
            )
    ) T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    WHERE (DateEntered) < '2015-04-15 15:17:03.693'
    ) T2
    ON T1.GID = T2.GID
    AND T1.MID = T2.MID
WHERE T1.Value <> T2.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should boil down to:

```
Select []
From A
Join B
on []
```

Yours is missing the first part, since your first `select` is actually part of the T1 subquery.  Adding another `Select * from` before your first parenthesis should solve the syntax issue.

Alternatively, the first part does not need to be a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
left outer join 
(
    Select * FROM Table1   
    where (DateEntered) < '2015-04-15 15:17:03.693'
) T2
    on T1.GID = T2.GID and T1.MID = T2.MID 
where T1.Value <> T2.Value
and T1.MMID IN 
(
    Select MAX(MMID) FROM Table1    
    where (DateEntered) >= '2015-04-15 15:17:03.693'
    group by GID, MID
)
```